# AS3 get variable from root timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, moviecliploader

i have this code on my main swf :

```
var btnLingua : Array = new Array(ITA,DE,LAT,EL);
var lingua:String = "ITA";

for(var i:int=0;i<btnLingua.length;i++){
    btnLingua[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,settaLingua);
}

function settaLingua(event:MouseEvent){
    trace("la lingua selezionata è : " + event.target.name);
    lingua=event.target.name;
    caricamento("scenaProva.swf");
}


var fl_Loader:Loader;

function caricamento(myURL:String):void {
    if(fl_Loader != null){
        contenitore.removeChild(fl_Loader);
        fl_Loader.unloadAndStop();
        fl_Loader = null;
    }
    fl_Loader = new Loader();
    fl_Loader.load(new URLRequest(myURL));
    fl_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, caricamentoCompleto);
}

function caricamentoCompleto(e:Event):void {
    contenitore.addChild(fl_Loader);
    fl_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, caricamentoCompleto);
}
```

and this on the movieClip :

```
trace("numero di elementi nella pagina : "+numChildren);
trace(MovieClip(root).lingua);
var lingua : String = MovieClip(root).lingua;

for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    var e:Object = getChildAt(i);

    if(e.name.indexOf("$"+lingua) >= 0){
        e.visible = true;
        trace(e.name + " contiene il carattere di linguaggio");
    }
    else if(e.name.indexOf("$")  >= 0){
        e.visible = false;
    }

}
```

when i try to get the variable lingua from my root movieclip i recive "UNDEFINED"
please can someone help me? i'm trying by 2 days...
sorry for bad english, i'm italian

Comment: When you say "on the movieclip" where exactly is that code?  Which movie clip?  Presumably the one you're loading in.   Most likely you're running into a security context issue.

Comment: i need to get the variable lingua in the second movieclip. the second movieclip is instanced by the first

Comment: @AlessandroZago You question is unclear. Try to give all details that can help other to understand the problem to get an answer. Explain what you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable `lingua` in your main timeline, you have `btnLingua` and `ling`.

Comment: sorry i have copied the wrong. but the error remains. i now edit the code

Answer (score 0):

I dont think in your Child SWF you can use the line: 
`var lingua : String = MovieClip(root).lingua;`
because that code will run before even the Child SWF has been added to the stage (Flash must do the first code to know what to show you).

So try something like...

```
var lingua : String = "";

addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onReady);

function onReady (evt : Event) : void
{
    trace("numero di elementi nella pagina : " + numChildren);
    //trace(MovieClip(root).lingua);

    lingua = this.parent.parent.lingua; //update string

    for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
    {
        var e:Object = getChildAt(i);

        if(e.name.indexOf("$"+lingua) >= 0)
        {
            e.visible = true;
            trace(e.name + " contiene il carattere di linguaggio");
        }
        else if(e.name.indexOf("$")  >= 0)
        { e.visible = false; }

    }
}
```

Comment: PS: The above code is untested since I'm not on Flash right now but you can try it. Comment if you still need help with it.

Comment: the string lingua is undefined

Comment: I see you have another **[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34125195/2057709)** here. So is this problem fixed now or you still need solution for string lingua?