# how to write on external file without ask in as3

Tags: file, actionscript-3

i have this code :

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.save("ciao coso","lingua.txt");
```

to write on an existing lingua.txt file.
the script works but every time he save ask me where to save the file... there is a way to save automatically on the existing lingua.txt file?
sorry for bad english, i'm italian.
maybe I have to use a different technique?

Comment: Are you using AIR?  or Flash Player?  If the former, you can do it (with the File and FileStream classes),  if the latter, you cannot (thank goodness!)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Ditto the "thank goodness!"

Comment: Take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31057995/2256820) where I'm talking about manners used to save data to local machine using Flash Player and AIR.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write to the user's file system in Flash Player; for security reasons, the user has to be the one saving the file. This is a very good thing when flash is running in a web browser.

As a workaround though, you can use [SharedObjects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) - which are cookie like in their behavior (not to be relied upon for persistent storage).

Now, if you're using Adobe AIR, you can save files with no user input.

You can do this with the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#open()) classes:

```
//do these 3 lines regardless of opening/saving
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory; //default place to save files - see the File class documentation for other shortcuts to common places
file = file.resolvePath("lingua.txt");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

//to open the file:
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var str:String = fileStream.readUTF();
fileStream.close();

//to save the file:
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTF("my string to write");
fileStream.close();
```

For more info on writing files, see [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc6.html):

Comment: with this code: http://prntscr.com/9bax2f i recive this errors : http://prntscr.com/9bax7v

Comment: Because you probably are not using AIR.  In your publish settings, the `target` must be set to AIR,  not flash player.

Comment: Did you get it figured out?