# How to silently save a file using ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

What script in which I can save multiple user's name in same text file automaticlly?

I made flash quiz in Flash CS6. I have following script in which I can save user name in `.txt` file but each time it ask to save file.

I used following script:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myfiles:FileReference=new FileReference();
saveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,saveFunction);

function saveFunction(event:MouseEvent):void
{       
    trace("ok");
    myfiles.save(inputtxt.text,".txt");
}
```

Comment: Please give your post a useful title! And does the save process work or not? I don't understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Save data into the **`SharedObject`** if you want a _"silent way"_

Comment: What is your platform?  AIR?  FlashPlayer?    If the former, you can do this, if the latter, you cannot - though as suggested you could use a sharedobject/cookie.    This is basically the same question, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125195/how-to-write-on-external-file-without-ask-in-as3/34125529#34125529

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
public function saveFile(info:String):void
{
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("file.txt");
    fileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(info);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

You can call it like:

saveFile("Hello World");

It will save your input silently.